# How to change the quantity of the item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i want to be able to increment or decrement the quantity of the item with a button, when the min or max limit of the available qty of the item has been reached, the user can not increment/ decrement anymore.

i can not come up with the rigt fix, what do i need to change ?

code Action:

```
export const increment = (qty, item) => (dispatch) => {
    if (qty <= item.qty) {
        qty++
    }
    dispatch({
        type: actions.INCREMENT,
        payload: {
            qty,
        },
    })
}

export const decrement = (qty, item) => (dispatch) => {
    if (qty >= item.qty) {
        qty--
    }

    dispatch({
        type: actions.DECREMENT,
        payload: {
            qty,
        },
    })
}
```

code Reducer:

```
 case actions.INCREMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                qty: action.payload.qty,
            }
        case actions.DECREMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                qty: action.payload.qty,
            }
```

code Button:

```
<button                  type="button"
                                                onClick={() =>
                                                    dispatch(
                                                        increment(
                                                            item.qty,
                                                            item
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            >
                                                +
                                            </button>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the problem you are trying to solve using redux which you can not solve without it?

Comment: I do not know about the syntax, yet the condition `qty <= item.qty` looks wrong since it can go one over the `qty`. Same goes for `qty >= item.qty` which can go one lower.

Comment: @fl-web the problem is, that the item qty doesnt get incremented when i dispatch the increment action

Comment: @Reactord I would suggest you to check if the action is even arriving at the reducer or not. If it is, then `console.log(action.payload.qty)` and see what its value is.

Comment: @usafder where should i do that in the Actions?

Comment: @Reactord no, in the reducer.

Comment: @usafder aight, thanks. I fixed the issue